# Unexpected path in PYTHONPATH when using Drake as a Bazel external

Tags: python, bazel, drake

I'm using drake as an external in another bazel project and it's adding `...runfiles/drake` as well as `...runfiles/drake/bindings` to the `PYTHONPATH`. The latter pretty much only includes `pydrake` (which is what I want), but the former is including a bunch of other directories as modules including common , examples, tools, and bindings which results in name collisions with my own project. Is this expected behavior? What's the best way to deal with this? I tested the examples in drake-external-examples/drake_bazel_external  and I'm seeing the same issue (relevant commit [here](https://github.com/pvarin/drake-external-examples/commit/a8d9c08e34db3c3d186dbe23f241b55688a8e893)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Best way to handle this is to make sure your imports are scoped to your project; e.g. instead of `from common import foo`, instead do `from drake_bazel_external.common import foo`.

Here's a snippet from a sample Bazel project that does this with Python:

https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/39f79009a2e89b987f072276d1921a282f63e6a1/python/bazel_py_example/mid/py3_bin.py#L3

---

To root cause, here's my attempt to instrument your repro with some more output, pinned to `drake@v0.18.0`:

[`drake_bazel_external/apps/bar.py`](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/drake-external-examples/blob/1165e06b243aa095996c3d019d84d036d6515812/drake_bazel_external/apps/bar.py#L27-L64) ([branch](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/drake-external-examples/blob/feature-pv-name-conflict))

Here's a preview of the Python paths, which corroborate what you're seeing:

```
path:
  {source_tree}/apps
  {runfiles}
  {runfiles}/drake/bindings
  {runfiles}/lcmtypes_bot2_core/lcmtypes
  {runfiles}/lcmtypes_bot2_core
  {runfiles}/lcmtypes_robotlocomotion/lcmtypes
  {runfiles}/lcmtypes_robotlocomotion
  {runfiles}/meshcat_python/src
  {runfiles}/spdlog
  {runfiles}/meshcat_python
  {runfiles}/lcm
  {runfiles}/ignition_math
  {runfiles}/drake
  {runfiles}/drake_external_examples
  /usr/lib/python36.zip
  /usr/lib/python3.6
  /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
common: {runfiles}/drake/common/__init__.py
```

Ultimately, this is expected behavior. Here's the Drake issue, and a related `bazelbuild` issue:

- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/7871
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7653

Best method is to use project-specific imports. For now, try to avoid this by using a more specific import.

I will re-open the Drake issue, but will keep it pegged at low priority since there's a better solution (IMO), and will require more infrastructure work to make it happen.

Thanks!

EDIT: To be specific, the thing that is most acutely tripping up your example is the fact that Bazel is generating `@drake//common:__init__.py`. It's only generated because of the `legacy_create_init` flag, as well as the fact that we want the file `libdrake_marker.so`.

There's still the fact that `drake` (among other repositories) are on the Python at all.

EDIT 2: Filed a new issue on Jeremy's request: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13320